# strange problem with breaking data into groups

Tags: r

I would like to build agegroup variable for a set of age. For some reason it did not turn out right. Could some one take a look and see what might be the cause? I really think I am doing everything right.

```
df<-structure(list(AGE = structure(c(10.1, 9.1, 7.1, 5.8, 2.8, 9.3, 
6.1, 4.4, 14.8, 14.6, 9.2, 13.7, 17.2, 14.2, 11.2, 8.8, 7.4, 
5.2, 8.8, 10.6, 14, 18.7, 8.4, 8.6, 4.8, 6.7, 10, 4.6, 9.1, 14.4, 
4.8, 6.9, 6.4, 12.8), label = "Age"), AGEU = c("YEARS", "YEARS", 
"YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS", 
"YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS", 
"YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS", 
"YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS", 
"YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS", "YEARS")), row.names = c(NA, -34L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), label = "DM")

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(  AGEGROUP =cut (AGE,
                        breaks=c(-Inf,0,0.001, 0.082,1.99,12.999,64.999,200),
                        right=TRUE,
                        labels = c("Foetus(0 yr)",
                                   "Neonate (0.001 - 0.082 yr)",
                                   "Infant(0.083-1.999 yrs)",
                                   "Child(2-12.999 yrs)",
                                   "Adolescent(13-17.999 yrs)",
                                   "Adult(18-64.999 yrs.)",
                                   "Elderly(65-199 yrs)")
                        ))
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't turn out right how? You haven't stated the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you'll have age in the range of `-Inf` to 0. Also you missed the break 17.99.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(  AGEGROUP =cut (AGE,
                          breaks=c(0,0.001, 0.082,1.99,12.999,17.99, 64.999,200),
                          right=TRUE,
                          labels = c("Foetus(0 yr)",
                                     "Neonate (0.001 - 0.082 yr)",
                                     "Infant(0.083-1.999 yrs)",
                                     "Child(2-12.999 yrs)",
                                     "Adolescent(13-17.999 yrs)",
                                     "Adult(18-64.999 yrs.)",
                                     "Elderly(65-199 yrs)")
  ))

df

#   AGE AGEU  AGEGROUP                 
#   <dbl> <chr> <fct>                    
# 1  10.1 YEARS Child(2-12.999 yrs)      
# 2   9.1 YEARS Child(2-12.999 yrs)      
# 3   7.1 YEARS Child(2-12.999 yrs)      
# 4   5.8 YEARS Child(2-12.999 yrs)      
# 5   2.8 YEARS Child(2-12.999 yrs)      
# 6   9.3 YEARS Child(2-12.999 yrs)      
# 7   6.1 YEARS Child(2-12.999 yrs)      
# 8   4.4 YEARS Child(2-12.999 yrs)      
# 9  14.8 YEARS Adolescent(13-17.999 yrs)
#10  14.6 YEARS Adolescent(13-17.999 yrs)
# … with 24 more rows
```